# access html element of parent of parent of ... the child component

Tags: angular

My code statement looks like this:

```
 this.elRef.nativeElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

How could I access an HTML element of an ancestor of the child component(my parent is at the top of the tree)?

I tried with [suggested @Host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35267146/accessing-a-property-in-a-parent-component-in-angular2-with-typescript) method but seems like I'm getting the copy of Host component, not the parent root element.

*Do we have a better syntax for the above statement?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your html put `#reference`

`<html-tag-element #yourParentEl></html-tag-element>`

then in your component:

```js
@ViewChild('yourParentEl') parent: any;
```

and you have in `this.parent` your element.

Comment: Wow.. getting parent element with @ViewChild and injecting parent component into the child and accessing the element is working as expected. Thank you very much.