# How can we access ancestor components' public properties?

Tags: angular

I want to access the public properties of the parent of the parent of the child component or in general of any ancestor component?

I found [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35267146/accessing-a-property-in-a-parent-component-in-angular2-with-typescript) for accessing properties of parent component but not for direct accessing any given ancestor in the hierarchy.

I noticed that some other framework provides direct access to the dom tree, can we have something like that into the angular for accessing component tree?

Comment: A global service is the solution, as described in the solution you posted. You can use it for any ancestor

Comment: I agree as well. If you want to share data, use services.

Comment: Could this be the only solution? can't we search for any element in the hierarchy of the current component tree by the direct method?

Comment: Tried with @Host() but getting different copy of the parent component..

Comment: What's wrong with services?

Comment: you can directly inject any parent in the hierarchy

Comment: ok.. I would try with this but using @Host() I were getting the different copy of the component.

Comment: Wow.. getting parent element with @ViewChild and injecting parent component into the child and accessing the element is working as expected. Thank you very much.