# Angular dependency injection of a component taking place without decorators

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-dependency-injection

I came across some code in which some components have access to their parent component instance but **I could not figure out how the "injection" takes place**.

I expected the code to fit in one of those [scenarios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35267146/accessing-a-property-in-a-parent-component-in-angular2-with-typescript#answer-35267202), but there is no dedicated attribute binding, nor `@Injectable` decorator in the parent component, nor `@Host` in children component constructor. Then, **how Angular can know it has to inject the parent component instance as the first argument in children components constructor?** Is this because parent and child components belong to the same module ? Is there any implicit behavior taking place here ?

---

#### Relevant code fragments

**Children components** receiving the parent instance **inherit from an common abstract class**
*(This class has nothing to do with angular components)*

```typescript
// The "parent" component file
import {GraphComponent} from "./graph.component";

export abstract class GraphElement implements OnDestroy {
    graph: GraphComponent;

    constructor(graph: GraphComponent, element: ElementRef) {
        this.graph = graph;
        // misc instructions …
    }
    …
}
```

**Children have similar @component decorator and constructor** :

```typescript
@Component({
  selector: 'g[lines]',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  template: `` // Empty string (not truncated), by the way why not using a directive instead?
})
export class LineComponent extends GraphElement {

    constructor(graph: GraphComponent, element: ElementRef) {
        super(graph, element);
        console.log(graph) // Does output the "parent" graph component instance to the console
    }
```

**"Parent" component declaration**:

```typescript
@Component({
  selector: 'graph',
  styleUrls: ['./graph.component.scss'],
  providers: [MiscService],
  // Truncated template
  template: `
         <svg>
             …
             <svg:g>
                 // The only input is pure d3Js chart data
                 <svg:g *ngIf="linesData" [lines]="linesData" />
             </svg:g>
             …
         </svg>
  `
})
export class GraphComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
    constructor(public elementRef: ElementRef, changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef /*, misc unrelated services */) {
        this.element = elementRef.nativeElement;
        // …
    }
    …
}
```

Comment: it has access to the parent component because of the module injector. I suggest you read [this part of the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection) for further explanation, but in two words, the module injector is aware of every class instance in the module, and can inject them when asked to.