# Is there any way to find out its parent component's identity/type in a child component level in Angular?

Tags: angular

Say, there's a relation between two components in Angular:

```js
// Parent component: ParentComponent
// Child component: ChildComponent

// in ParentComponent template
<pp-child></pp-child>

------

export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    // wonder if there's something like:
    // private parentRef: HostParentRef
  ) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.parentRef); // This would print ParentComponent
  }
}
```

What I want to know is if there's a way to find out its parent component's **type** in `ChildComponent` level. If there is, I would get `ParentComponent` in this case.

Any insight would be appreciated!

**Edit:**
I'm not talking about accessing parent's property or communicating between two. I'm just simply wondering about parent component's **type** of a component on runtime.

Comment: what you mean by identity?. if you want to share any data from parent component to child you can pass it as props. it will be helpful if you can describe what is your current problem is!

Comment: Have you looked at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35267146/accessing-a-property-in-a-parent-component?

Comment: @RashiqKodakkad Component Type I suppose. In above case, `ParentComponent`  is the case.

Comment: @DongBinKim please show demonstration

Comment: @shaktimaan I have but I don't see any clue which has to do with my question.

Comment: I can't understand what you want exactly. why do you get parents type? if you want to receive props from parent you can do it. I wonder if any other problems you have. please share your code if possible.

Comment: @DongBinKim I really want to help you. Please tell me want do you want to do by referring parent component. (like change style or property). Please use code sandbox to demonstrate your problem. i think it will help others to understand problem

Comment: @AmirChristian I have no particular purpose with it. I just simply want to know if it's possible.

Comment: @RashiqKodakkad I'm not curious about communication between child and parent component. I just simply wonder if it's possible to know the parent component's type in the child component level. No particular purpose with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by passing a parameter as the name of the parent so that your child component can get to know who is the parent component and what data is to be processed

```
<pp-child [parentInfo]="parentData"> </pp-child>
```

And take the input in child component as

```
@Input() parentInfo;
constructor(){
 console.log(parentInfo);
}
```

You can also get the info of the parent using this keyword also

```
<pp-child [parentInfo]="this"> </pp-child>
```

Then when you check the parentInfo keyword then you get the whole parent component info also.
Or  you can get the parent Element of a element as we do in javascript but it will give you the direct parent element like div if it in a div

Comment: Possibly but I wonder if there's other Angular built in annotation or something for this purpose.

Comment: No as per my knowledge their is no such thing

Comment: answer edit use this for all info about the parent into the child

Answer (score -1):

You can use `eventEmitter`.

This is a small example which will give you some insight:

**parent.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: `
    Message: {{message}}
    <app-child (messageEvent)="receiveMessage($event)"></app-child>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css']
})
export class ParentComponent {

  constructor() { }

  message:string;

  receiveMessage($event) {
    this.message = $event
  }
}
```

**child.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template: `
      <button (click)="sendMessage()">Send Message</button>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent {

  message: string = "Hola!"

  @Output() messageEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();

  constructor() { }

  sendMessage() {
    this.messageEvent.emit(this.message)
  }
}
```

This URL will get some help:
https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer the question the OP posed.