# How can I defer resolution of a dependency in the injector?

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to resolve a configuration object for the injector when `ngOnInit` is called.

This is what I am trying to do:

```html
<my-component [config]="someConfig"></my-component>
```

```
// my.component.ts

import { CONFIG_TOKEN } from 'injector_tokens';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: '<p>need to delay dependency injector resolution... but how?! it's not in the docs...</p>',
  styleUrls: [],
  providers: [
    SomeService
  ]
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() config: Config;
  ngOnInit(): void {
    // I want to be able to now add to the injector's providers array: 
    // { provide: CONFIG_TOKEN, useValue: this.config }
    // how can I do that?
  }

}
```

```
// some_service.ts

import { CONFIG_TOKEN } from 'injector_tokens';

export class SomeService {
  constructor(@Inject(CONFIG_TOKEN) config: Config) {
    // config should be the config object passed in via html attribute
  }
}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: It's not in the docs because there's no mechanism for that. You can inject the injector, then ask it for an instance of a given dependency, but at a certain point the level of inherent coupling means you're not benefiting from DI - what's the actual _context_ here?

Comment: I’m wondering the same. Context. There is also a runtime versus build time problem here, things are statically analyzed by the compiler here (like the providers array).

Comment: @jonrsharpe dynamic configuration object passed in via template `<my-component config="someConfig">` being available to all services used by the component, without having to manually new up said services in component..  Seems like a pretty reasonable thing that should be possible...

Comment: @jonrsharpe I edited the code in my question to add a little more context...

Comment: Does it? If you don't have the value until after the component is created then you can't create the services so you can't create the component.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35267146/accessing-a-property-in-a-parent-component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it' usually an anti-pattern, but I see the use. Basically you have a config which comes to the component via template, but the config is also for the service instance underlying the component's business logic.

Seems fair.

I think your best bet is to trade the construction-time usability of your service (usually a nice characteristic) with an `Init(config: Config)` method, to be called inside the `ngOnInit` method of your component. In this way, you keep the Dependency Injection provided parameters in the service constructor, you keep the `providers` definition in your component easy peasy, and there is no direct usage of the injector.

If you want, you could even call the `SomeService.Init` method in the setter of the component's input property:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: '<p>whatever...</p>',
  styleUrls: [],
  providers: [ SomeService ]
})
export class MyComponent {

  private _config: Config = null;
  @Input() get config(): Config {
    return _config;
  }
  set config(v: Config) {
    _config = v;
    this.someService.Init(v);
  }

  constructor(Self() private someService: SomeService) {
  }
}
```

Comment: bummer..  but ok, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I see an issue from the get go.

```
<my-component config="someConfig"></my-component>
```

this would bind the string `"someConfig"`

It should be:

```
 <my-component [config]="someConfig"></my-component>
```

this would bind the variable `someConfig` from the holding component component.

for the injection stuff. I dont see you need injection if you have `someConfig` available already but just passes it into `my-component`

Edit: For the service you have 3 levels you can provide it.
On Root, Module and Component level

for modules and components its done the same way.

```
@Component({
    selecter : 'my-component',
    ...
    providers: [ MyService ]
})
export class MyComponent { ... }
```

Now you might want to use a factory or something like that to parse the extra value. Or you could have create a injection token which you set in the providers instead.
relevant source for how to: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers

Comment: yes, the missing square brackets was a typo (i updated my code in the question)...  I don't understand your last sentence.  How can someConfig be made available to services used within the component without manually newing up the services or manually setting the config as properties on them.

Comment: You can provide the service on component level as well. I updated the answer. There is a couple of ways of doing it, but you should check the link i added, what fits you needs the best.

Comment: No, it doesn't, AFAICT. The problem is that the config is filled _after_ construction, so _after_ the dependency injection does its job.

Comment: @A.Chiesa yeah if that is the case it should probably just be a setter for the service.