# Angular 2 EventEmitter

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an issue where the EventEmitter does not output the value to parent component. Here is how i am setup.

*main.component.ts (short version)*

```
...     

@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
templateUrl: '/app/views/main.ejs',
directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
providers:[AuthService],
inputs:['userLoggedIn']
})

@RouteConfig([
{path:'/logout', name: 'Logout', component: AuthComponent},

])

export class AppComponent implements OnInit, CanReuse{  

    constructor(private _auth_service: AuthService){

         this._auth_service.authChanged.subscribe(data=>this.authChangedHandler(data));

    }

    public authChangedHandler($event){

        alert($event);

    }

}

...
```

*auth.component.ts (short version)*

```
export class AuthComponent implements OnInit, CanReuse{

public loggedIn = false;

public user = {};

@Output()
authChanged: EventEmitter<string>;

public selectedTab = "/login";

    constructor(private _router: Router, private _location:Location,private _http: Http, private _auth_service: AuthService){

        this.authChanged = new EventEmitter();

        this.authChanged.emit("authChanged");

    }

}
```

*main.ejs (short version)*

```
<nav (authChanged)="authChangedHandler($event)"></nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

*auth.service.ts*

```
export class AuthService {

public authChanged: EventEmitter<string>;

constructor(private _http: Http){

    this.authChanged = new EventEmitter();
    this.authChanged.emit("authChanged");

    }

}
```

**EDIT:**
I have added `AuthService` code which i inject into main component. It should work now but does not.

Comment: Did you get a solution for it ? I am also looking to capture an event which is  emitted from the component added in @RouteConfig

Comment: @Sanjeev Yes i did. I used Service Events. I have a created a plunker here (https://plnkr.co/edit/WZ5HbvBP5LMSqZQtixoG?p=preview)

Comment: The idea is to inject a Service at bootstrap and that service will contain the eventemitter which every component can subscribe to, globally.

Comment: thanks @R. Hussain: but it ll be great if there is a way to bubble up the event.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Events emitted by `EventEmitter` don't bubble. If the element is added to a `router-outlet` only the `router-outlet` receives the event but not the element containing the `router-outlet`.

You could use a shared service to communicate between the parent and the child element.

For shared service see

- https://github.com/escardin/angular2-community-faq/blob/master/services.md#how-do-i-communicate-between-components-using-a-shared-service
- [Global Events in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34700438/global-events-in-angular-2)

If you register the shared service in the `providers: []` list of the parent component, the service is shared only between the parent element and all of its descendants. If you only add it to `bootstrap(MyApp, [ ..., SharedService])` the whole application shares one instance.

Comment: Could you please be more elaborate about the shared service? Maybe some code?

Comment: Yes i saw and i opted for Service Events and made changes to above code. Please see my edits.

Comment: If you emit the event in the constructor of the `AuthService` the event is alredy sent before `AppComponent` can subscribe. For the test wrap the `emit(event)` in `AuthService` in a `setTimeout()` to give `AppComponent` time to subscribe. In a real-world application it would fire later anyway.

Comment: Well, i have already tried emitting inside a `logout` method in AuthService but to no avail :(

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer: you are right, but isn't there any way to bubble up the event to the element containing the router outlet ?

Comment: I think the way to go is a shared service containing an EventEmitter, where the child invokes the event and the parent listens.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, the `nav` isn't the parent component of the `AuthComponent` one. The latter is involved in routing (see `router-outlet`). That's why you can't receive the event for the registered expression on the `nav` element in the HTML.

Comment: Please see my edits. The `nav` issue should not matter now since i'm using Service Events. Right?

Comment: Yes, but you should use this: `this._auth_service.authChanged.emit('authChanged');` ;-) to trigger the event...

Comment: But i emit it from the service. Not from the component.

Comment: Oh sorry! Perhaps your service isn't completely a shared one (I mean by the whole application). To be sure, set it as provider when bootstrapping your application: `bootstrap(AppComponent, [ AuthService ]);`. Don't forget to remove it from `providers` attributes you can have at the level of your components. This is because of hierarchical injectors. See this answer for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34804298/whats-the-best-way-to-inject-one-service-into-another-in-angular-2-beta/34807397.