# What Does the Class Constructor Inputs Do In TypeScript Ionic 2?

Tags: angular, ionic2

I'm new at Ionic2 and Angular. What does declaring a variable as a constructor input do in the class?

```
import { LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';

export class MyPage {
  constructor(public loadingCtrl: LoadingController <-----) {
  }

  presentLoading() {
    let loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: "Please wait...",
      duration: 3000
    });
    loader.present();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> What does declaring a variable as a constructor input

Constructor parameters are like method or function parameters that allows to pass parameters

```
let page = new MyPage(aLoadingController)
```

except that you don't create `MyPage` instances yourself but Angular2's dependency injection (DI) does it for you.

DI looks up it's registry if it finds a provider that matches the parameter type (or `@Inject(xxx)`) annotation if there is any) and then passes an instance created by a found provider to the `new MyPage(...)` call.

For this to work Angular2 needs a decorator like `@Page()`, `@Component()`, `@Directive()`, `@Pipe()`, `@Injectable()` on the class. If it finds such a decorator it analyses the constructor parameter list to know what needs to be injected.

If `public` or `private` is prepended to the constructor parameter, then also an instance level property is created and the passed value assigned to this property automatically (pure TypeScript feature)

- I don't know Ionic and if there are some special things to consider.

  - I have seen [What is static get parameters() purpose in Ionic 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35919593/what-is-static-get-parameters-purpose-in-ionic-2) and I am not sure if it is required or optional to configure what should be passed to the constructor using it.

Comment: Thanks! So it seems that Angular2 does a lot of things in the background like looking for the provider.

Comment: DI is the Angular part that does this, the rest is DOM rendering and change detection and other stuff