# What does this signify in IONIC 2?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, static, ionic2

What does the code below signify?
I am having a hard time understanding it!

```
static get parameters() {
    return [[NavController]];
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is static get parameters() purpose in Ionic 2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35919593/what-is-static-get-parameters-purpose-in-ionic-2)

Comment: Duplicate indeed. Also, this is not neccessary for ionic 2 applications. Just a bit of metadata, I find it quite unneccessary