# Sharing async data in service angular2

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm probably missing something very obvious, but what I am trying to do is share data that I get from a server asynchronously, between components.

This is what my service looks like:

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {ApiService} from './api.service';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
    private user: Object

    constructor(private _api: ApiService) {}

    getUser(user) {
        return this.user
    }

    setUser(slug) {
        return Promise.resolve(this._api.GET('users/' + slug + '/?slug=true').subscribe(
            data => { this.user = data.json; return data.json; },
            (err)=>console.log(err)
         ))
    }
}
```

Since the process is asynchronous I need to Promise the response, however the promised response returns the actual subscribe object, not the returned `data.json`.

This is for a profile page, it consists of nested routes, so I can't pass data to the routed components. One of the routed components is Posts, and after loading the profile, this should start fetching posts **OF THE CURRENT USER IN THE SERVICE**.

So this is what I need to happen:

1. User goes to his/her profile.
2. Service calls setUser('foo'), once response, show profile page.
3. Fetch the user's post into the Posts component using the service's getUser()

The api service looks like this:

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, Response, RequestOptions, Headers, Request, RequestMethod} from 'angular2/http';
import {GlobalService} from '../app.service';
import 'rxjs/Rx';


@Injectable()
export class ApiService {
    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    apiURL = 'http://localhost:8000/api/';
    assetURL = 'http://localhost:8000/media/';

    GET(url) {
        var headers = new Headers(), authtoken = localStorage.getItem('authtoken');
        headers.append("Content-Type", 'application/json');

        if (authtoken) {
        headers.append("Authorization", 'Token ' + authtoken)
        }
        headers.append("Accept", 'application/json');

        var requestoptions = new RequestOptions({
            method: RequestMethod.Get,
            url: this.apiURL + url,
            headers: headers
        })

        return this.http.request(new Request(requestoptions))
        .map((res: Response) => {
            if (res) {
                return { status: res.status, json: res.json() }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Excuse the poor question if it was, I am still learning angular2 and couldn't find a concrete solution to this online.

Comment: What is the `Promise` for you return from `setUser()`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer If you refer to my previous question that you answered, it's for the Profile component, after the promise, the profile component loads the profile page for the user. And then any child components can use getUser to fetch the user that the service set.

Comment: Can you please post the link, I can't remember.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36877226/pass-component-property-to-routedata-in-angular2/36881624?noredirect=1#comment61342558_36881624 I'm trying to implement a global service, like you said.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/36291681/217408 but that doesn't really answer what you need the `Promise` for.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer 'Cannot find name Observable' Is there a module I have to import?

Comment: ` <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.15/Rx.js"></script>`

Comment: I have that already, tried importing it and I get the same error.

Comment: `import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110394/discussion-between-sebastian-olsen-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Answer (score 0):

If you need a promise, you could use something like this:

```
setUser(slug) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this._api.GET('users/' + slug + '/?slug=true').subscribe(
        data => {
          this.user = data.json;
          resolve(data.json);
        },
        (err) => {
          console.log(err);
          reject(err);
        }
     ))
}
```

Otherwise you resolve the subscription and not the received data...

Answer (score 0):

If you need a `Promise` you can just use `toPromise`

```
import {toPromise} from 'rxjs/operator/toPromise'

...

   setUser(slug) {
        return this._api.GET('users/' + slug + '/?slug=true')
        .map(
            data => { this.user = data.json; return data.json; }
         )
         .toPromise()
         .catch(err)=>console.log(err));
    }
```