# using $on and $broadcast with angular 2

Tags: angular

Currently with angularjs 1, I am using the `$on` and `$broadcast` event mechanisms, which are available as part of `$rootscope` and `$scope`, to handle communication between a controller and a service. However, with the introduction of AngularJS 2, `$rootscope` and `$scope` will become unavailable. So, if I want to make my application AngularJS 2-compliant, then what should I do to get the same effect as `$on` and `$broadcast`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Global Events in Angular 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34700438/global-events-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 11):

You could use a shared service containing a property of type `Observable`. Here is a sample implementation:

```
export class SharedService {
  observable: Observable;
  observer: Observer;

  constructor() {
    this.observable = Observable.create((observer:Observer) => {
      this.observer = observer;
    }).share();
  }

  broadcast(event) {
    this.observer.next(event);
  }

  on(eventName, callback) {
    this.observable.filter((event) => {
      return event.name === eventName;
    }).subscribe(callback);
  }
}
```

You can notice that you need to share the observable because it's cold by default.

An important thing consists in defining your service when bootstrapping your application to be able to use the same instance within the whole application:

```
bootstrap(AppComponet, [ SharedService ]);
```

Here is the corresponding plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/bpIVxRrWggLVrS9BdQ6w?p=preview.

See this question for more details:

- [Delegation: EventEmitter or Observable in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376854/delegation-eventemitter-or-observable-in-angular2/35568924)

Comment: Can I use EventEmitter or Observable with angular 1 or it is only available with angular 2? Currently, I am using $broadcast & $on in my application for sending Signal R updates.

Comment: rxjs isn't used by Angular1 itself whereas it's part of Angular2 out of the box. I think that this library could be used in Angular1 because it's a third-party one but I never tried...

Comment: Thanks Thierry. So, If I understand correctly "EventEmitter" is from NodeJs & "Observable" is part of RxJs.

Comment: EventEmitter is an Angular2 class that extends `Subject` (a class from Rxjs). It's part of the core of the framework to implement / handle custom events.

Comment: One problem I am facing using this, is that `sharedService.on('eventName',()=>{})` is triggered even when the view is not active. How do I have this?

Comment: `.share()` doesn't work after upgrading to rxjs 5.5.2. Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: create is depricated, Generic type 'Observable<T>' requires 1 type argument(s), theres a lot wrong with this these days so anyone looking here prolly shouldnt try this anymore

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing in Angular2. Custom shared services are used for this. See also [Global Events in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34700438/global-events-in-angular-2/34703015#34703015)

Comment: With Angular 1 is it possible to handle broadcast without using "$on" & "$broadcast"?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with that. I don't know Angular1 well.

Answer (score 0):

AngularJs inbuilt does not provide Broadcast and Emit, you can implement with custom code like [Plnkr](http://embed.plnkr.co/aJe5SUtFlnpmGXWA5eHk/)