# Rxjs 5: share is not a function

Tags: angular, rxjs

After updating to RxJs 5 I am getting the following error:

`share is not a function`

**Code:**

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Observer } from 'rxjs/Observer';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { share } from "rxjs/operators/share";
import * as m from '../../models/app.models';

@Injectable()
export class SharedService {
    observable: Observable<any>;
    observer: Observer<any>;

    constructor() {
        var temp = Observable.create((observer: Observer<any>) => {
            this.observer = observer;
        });
        this.observable = temp.share(); <- Error here
    }

    broadcast(event: m.SharedEventModel) {
        this.observer.next(event);
    }

    on(eventName, callback) {
        return this.observable.filter((event) => {
            return event.Name === eventName;
        }).subscribe(callback);
    }
}
```

Trying to make a globalEvents following http://stackoverflow.com/a/36174340/3955513

RxJs Version: 5.5.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the working service.

I've updated Thierry Templier's plunker from the question you're using as a reference, [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/RpETlKPhLIyKMMfjnrQn)

**Note**, `import { share } from "rxjs/operators";` not `import { share } from "rxjs/operator/share";` as stated elsewhere. See [lettable-operators.md](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/lettable-operators.md#usage)

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Observer } from 'rxjs/Observer';
import { share } from "rxjs/operators";   // lettable operator, tree-shakeable
import { filter } from "rxjs/operators";

@Injectable()
export class SharedService {
  observable: Observable<any>;
  observer: Observer<any>;

  constructor() {
    var temp = Observable.create((observer: Observer<any>) => {
      this.observer = observer;
    });
    this.observable = temp.pipe(share());
  }

  broadcast(event) {
    this.observer.next(event);
  }

  on(eventName, callback) {
    this.observable.pipe(filter(x => x.name === eventName))
      .subscribe(callback);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're importing lettable "`share()`" operator but trying to use it as the original "patch" operators.

You should use it as follows:

```
import { share } from "rxjs/operator/share";

...

this.observable = share(temp);
```

Or like this:

```
import { share } from "rxjs/operators/share";

...

this.observable = temp.pipe(share());
```

Comment: This worked but got another error at `this.observable.filter` saying `lift of undefined in filter.js`

Comment: @ShyamalParikh I don't know what your app does so I can't help you.

Comment: Changed to `this.observable.pipe(filter(x => x.Name === eventName)).subscribe(callback);` gives typescript error saying `this` context of `void` is not assignable to method's `this` type of `Observable<{}>`