# $broadcast $on in angular 2

Tags: angular, ionic2, onesignal

I'm trying to implement `$broadcast` and `$on` in `>ionic2` and I found this solution here in Stackoverflow

[using $on and $broadcast with angular js 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36174340)
, well I thought it was working perfect, since now.

I've implemented `oneSignal` like this :

```
var iosSettings = {};
iosSettings["kOSSettingsKeyAutoPrompt"] = true;
iosSettings["kOSSettingsKeyInAppLaunchURL"] = false;
window["plugins"].OneSignal.startInit("123123", "123123")
.inFocusDisplaying(window["plugins"].OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.None)
.iOSSettings(iosSettings)
.handleNotificationReceived(function (jsonData) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(jsonData));
    if (jsonData["payload"] != null && jsonData["payload"]["additionalData"] != null) {
        alert("first"); //<------ FIRST ALERT
        var data = jsonData["payload"]["additionalData"];
        notificationOpenedCallback(data);
    }
})
.handleNotificationOpened(function (jsonData) {
    if (jsonData["notification"] != null && jsonData["notification"]["payload"] != null) {
        var data = jsonData["notification"]["payload"]["additionalData"];
        notificationOpenedCallback(data);
    }
})
.endInit();
```

My `notificationOpenedCallback(data)` has this on its body

```
var notificationOpenedCallback = function (jsonData) {
                if (jsonData != null) {
                    if (jsonData["type"] == "example") {
                        alert("second"); //<------ SECOND ALERT
                        this.sharedService.broadcast({
                            name: 'example'
                        });
                    }
```

Since here is OK, the problem comes when I'm from the other page...

```
this.sharedService.on('example', (event) => {
            alert("pewpew"); // <--- 3RD ALERT
        });
```

I don't get what I'm doing wrong I have an `Ionic1` app and I hace the same code, the only different thing is that I've created the `sharedServiceProvider` to "emulate" the `$broadcast` and `$on`, this is my class

```
export class SharedServiceServiceProvider {
  observable: any;
  observer: any;   
  constructor() {
    this.observable = Observable.create(observer => {
      this.observer = observer;
    }).share();
  } 
  broadcast(event) {
    this.observer.next(event);
  } 
  on(eventName, callback) {
    this.observable.filter((event) => {
      return event.name === eventName;
    }).subscribe(callback);
  }  
}
```

### Problem

I'm able to see the **FIRST, SECOND** alert, but not the 3rd one.

### EDIT

I've created a sample demo here on [`GitHub-oneSignal-ionic2`](https://github.com/joancolmenerodev/oneSignal-ionic2). The only thing you have to do (if you wanna play with that) is change the `OneSignal key` and create a template for your notification.

### UPDATE EDIT

I've changed the `.handleNotificationOpened(function (jsonData) {` to `.handleNotificationOpened((jsonData) => {` now, the `alert()` is shown, **BUT** the problem is that I have something like this :

```
this.sharedService.on('example', (event) => {
            alert("test");
            this.showStatus();
            this.getActiveGuy(function () {
            });
        });
```

But seems like those 2 methods are called but not doing the job, those methos do a refresh of the page and it does not... and I have to make the refresh (Scroll to down) and then it refreshes, **BUT** that's why on my `onRefresh()` I have those methods....

Comment: Do you have any repository with stripped-down code to reproduce it?

Comment: @yurzui where could I put this project?

Comment: For instance on github

Comment: Ya, but I can not put the keys on it... :(

Comment: @yurzui see my edit

Comment: Are you sure that `this.sharedService.broadcast` is called without any errors? Maybe you got cannot read property `broadcast` of `undefined`? I would suggest you using arrow function to keep correct `this`

Comment: @yurzui may you put an example of your guess?

Comment: Something like `var notificationOpenedCallback = (jsonData) => {`

Comment: @yurzui put that as an answer, maybe it's the correct one..

Comment: You already have answer:)

Comment: @yurzui The posted answer pinpoints the problem, but does not give the 'proper' solution, which is using the arrow function. You should post that an an answer

Comment: @yurzui see my edit let me know if you have an answer to this :(

Comment: If it still doesn't update UI you can try running code inside angular zone through `ngZone.run`

Comment: I had the same code in Ionic1 and I had problems and I solved it doing `$digest()` something to do with this?

Answer (score 3):

This is issue from `this` is `undefined` which is not call `this.sharedService`.

In javascript it known by `lexical scoping`, let's quotes this [blog](https://derickbailey.com/2015/09/28/do-es6-arrow-functions-really-solve-this-in-javascript/):

> The ES6 arrow function syntax uses “lexical scoping” to figure out
>   what the value of “this” should be. Lexical scoping is fancy way of
>   saying it uses “this” from the surrounding code… the code that
>   contains the code in question.

or from `typescript` [documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/'this'-in-TypeScript#user-content-use-instance-functions):

> Good/bad: This creates an additional closure per method per instance
>   of the class. If this method is usually only used in regular method
>   calls, this is overkill. However, if it's used a lot in callback
>   positions, it's more efficient for the class instance to capture the
>   `this` context instead of each call site creating a new closure upon
>   invoke.

simply to fix your problem is (as mention by yurzui comment also):

```
var notificationOpenedCallback = function (jsonData) {
. . .
}
```

to:

```
let notificationOpenedCallback = (jsonData) => {
. . .
}
```

Comment: See my update edit, I did it but the problem is that is not "refreshing" or not updating UI I don't know why

Answer (score 2):

Problem is here

```
var notificationOpenedCallback = function (jsonData) {
    if (jsonData != null) {
       if (jsonData["type"] == "example") {
            alert("second"); //<------ SECOND ALERT
            this.sharedService.broadcast({
                name: 'example'
            });
        }
```

The `this` keyword is referencing the `notificationOpenedCallback`
function and it can not access the `sharedService`. What you can do is move this function `notificationOpenedCallback(data)` to the class object and that should solve the issue.

Comment: Nice work finding the problem. You should take a look at the last comment on the question (by David) and update your answer with the solution too.