# $scope.$on replacement in Angular 2+

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs, typescript, angular2-services

in my component which I am migrating Angular js to angular 2+, I have $scope.$on which is getting data broadcasted from controller which is in Angular js. is there any replacement for $scope.$on(){} which can receive data from controller

Comment: you might want to have a read on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). tl;dr; Show what you have already tried and what is preventing you from progressing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36174273/using-on-and-broadcast-with-angular-2