# How to broadcast events from app.component to router-outlet in angular2

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-routing

I have created a service that has a stream$ that will emit an event, I hope after the app.component fires the stream$ emit, the child component in the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` will be able to subscribe it, but now the problem I have is even if it subscribes it in the constructor, the subscription call back never gets fired.

I wonder if this is different from when emitting events through a stream service?

What is the best practice?

Comment: Here is my implementation of such a service that allows to get the nth last values upon subscription. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46027693/angular2-4-broadcast-service-using-rxjs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most simple way is to create event bus service:

```
export class EventBusService
{
    bus:Subject<Event> = new Subject<Event>();

    dispatch(data:Event){
        this.bus.next(data);
    }

    //its up to you how to implement it:
    listen(type:string):Observable<Event> {
        return this.bus.filter(event=>event.type === type);
    }
}
```

Use dependency injection:

```
bootstrap(App, [EventBusService]);
```

Component constructor:

```
constructor(bus:EventBusService){
   bus.dispatch(new Event());
   bus.listen('load').subscribe((e)=>{console.log('loaded');})
}
```