# Suggestions on how to implement a message service in angular2 using rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs

My goal is:

- Allow all the messages of the app to be managed in a single
  component.

So far I came up with is:

- MessageService: Singleton. Whoever wants to send a message calls addMsg here.

Messages are Subject observables.

`newMessages: Subject<IMessage> = new Subject<IMessage>();`

- MessageViewer: A component that listens to MessageService and display the messages.

`constructor(private _msgService: MessageService) {
   this._msgService.getMessages().subscribe(
      data => this.showMsg(data)
   )
}`

Full demo here.
https://plnkr.co/edit/aCXMtmiQhRL63EfT5lIy

Is that a good implementation or there is a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Looks fine ;-) The remaining part is where you register this service. If it's for the whole application, it's when bootstrapping or in the main component...

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bangular2%5D+event+bus and in particular http://stackoverflow.com/a/36782616/215945

Comment: Personally, I probably prefer using Observables as apposed to a Message Bus. This is how I realized the power of Event-Driven Architectures and Mediation a long time ago with KnockoutJS. I think Observables are more performant and easier to implement into a State-Machine; all you have to do on a Mediator is provide `.publish` & `.subscribe` methods that implement their own Message Filtering -- *which you want for Message Bussing anyway*; takes out some of the headache & boilerplate, though. **I'd give you a thumbs up for being one of the few to even go for this :)**.