# How listen event after Output in angular 2?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, output

In one component I emit some data

```
@Output() search: EventEmitter<string> =
      new EventEmitter<string>(); 

onChange(searchText) {
    this.search.emit(searchText);
    console.log(searchText);
  };
```

How I can listen 'searchText' value in another component?

Another component isn`t child of first component.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Global Events in Angular 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34700438/global-events-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 2):

The way you defined your output means that the parent component can be notified when corresponding events occur:

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <search (search)="doSomething($event)"></search>
  `,
  directives: [ SearchComponent ]
})
export class SomeComponent {
  doSomething(searchText:string) {
    (...)
  }
}
```

Assuming the selector of the component you described is `search`.

If the relation between the component that triggers the event and the one that listens is different, you should consider to use an observable within a shared service. See this doc for more details:

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service