# angular 2 – change interface in global service through component and update changed interface in another

Tags: typescript, angular

I am playing around with angular 2. I want to build a global service that holds an interface. This interface can be changed through a `HeaderComponent`. After the user changed the interface through the `HeaderComponent` the interface has also been changed in another `ChildComponent`. Therefor I worked with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34703015) found on stack overflow.

Let's say I have an interface and 2 different classes. Each of these classes are holding a different type of the interface.

**MyInterface**

```
export interface MyInterface {
    key: string,
}
```

**ClassA**

```
import { MyInterface } from './interfaces/my-interface';
export class ClassA {
    type = "A";
    _interface: MyInterface = {
        key: "value1",
    };
}
```

**ClassB**

```
import { MyInterface } from './interfaces/my-interface';
export class ClassB {
    type = "B";
    _interface: MyInterface = {
        key: "value2",
    };
}
```

A global service is implementing this interface.

**GlobalService**

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter }    from '@angular/core';

import { ClassA } from './classes/class-a';
import { ClassB } from './classes/class-b';
import { MyInterface } from './interfaces/my-interface';

@Injectable()
export class GlobalService {

    public interfaceChanged: EventEmitter<MyInterface>;
    _interface: MyInterface;

    interfaceList: string[] = [];

    interfaces = [
        new ClassA(),
        new ClassB()
    ];

    selectedInterface: string;

    constructor() {
        this.interfaceChanged = new EventEmitter<MyInterface>();
        for (var i = 0; i < this.interfaces.length; i++)
            this.interfaceList.push(this.interfaces[i].type);
        this.changeInterface(this.interfaceList[0]);
    }

    changeInterface(_interface: string): void {
        if (this.interfaceList.includes(_interface)) {
            this.selectedInterface = _interface;
            for (var i = 0; i < this.interfaces.length; i++) {
                if (this.interfaces[i].type == this.selectedInterface) {
                    this._interface = this.interfaces[i]._interface;
                    this.interfaceChanged.emit(this.interfaces[i]._interface);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now the `HeaderComponent` which is implemented as directive in `app.component.ts`

**app.component.ts**

```
import { HeaderDirective } from './directives/header';
import { FooterDirective } from './directives/footer';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <my-header></my-header>
    <div class="container">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
    <my-footer></my-footer>
  `,
  styleUrls: [ ],
  directives: [HeaderDirective, FooterDirective, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

is able to change the interface through a select field:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MyInterface } from './interfaces/my-interface';
import { LanguageService } from './services/global-service';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-header',
    template: `
      <select (change)="change($event.target.value)">
        <option *ngFor=" let _interface of interfaceList ">{{ _interface }}</option>
      </select>
    `,
})
export class HeaderComponent {

    selectedInterface: string;
    interfaceList: string[];
    _interface: MyInterface;

    constructor(private globalService: GlobalService) {
        this.selectedInterface = this.globalService.selectedInterface;
        this.interfaceList = this.globalService.interfaceList;
        this._interface = this.globalService._interface;
    }

    change(_interface: string) {
        this.globalService.changeInterface(_interface);
    }
}
```

So far so good. After I changed the interface through my `HeaderComponent` I want that the interface also be changed in another `ChildComponent` that is going to be displayed through `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

```
import { Component, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { GlobalService } from './services/global-service';
import { MyInterface } from './interfaces/my-interface';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-child',
  template: `
    <p>Test: {{ _interface.key }}</p>
  `,
})
export class ChildComponent {

    private _interface: MyInterface;

    constructor(private globalService: GlobalService) {

        this.globalService.interfaceChanged
                          .toPromise()
                          .then(_interface => {
                              this.changeLanguage(_interface);
                          })
                          .catch(err => {
                              console.log(err);
                          });
    }

    changeInterface(_interface: MyInterface) {
        this._interface = _interface;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the change of the interface through the `HeaderComponent` is working but the interface doesn't change for the `ChildComponent`. The `changeInterface(interface: MyInterface)` function in my `ChildComponent` isn't even called. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34703015) the user is working with:

```
...
constructor(globalService: GlobalService) {
    globalService.interfaceChanged.subscribe(_interface => this.changeInterface(_interface));
}
...
```

for the `ChildComponent`. But if I do so there is an error within my sublime editor: "Parameter 'interface' implicitly has an 'any' type." So what am I doing wrong? What am I missing here?

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/g9XZPPZZCTK5ATCmotk7?p=preview) you can see it on Plunker.

Comment: Why are you using 'interface' as field name? It just make things worse when you need to debug.

Comment: @HarryNinh this is just for better understanding I thought. In the original code this variable isn't called `interface`. I can change it.

Comment: @HarryNinh I changed it to `_interface`

Comment: just, can you make these to Plunker? So if somebody wants to experiment with your code and fix the issues, they can easily do so.

Comment: @HarryNinh This could take a while ^^

Comment: @HarryNinh just added the Plunker at the bottom.

Comment: Hey, check this out: https://plnkr.co/edit/udQFsQKHww7VMnYFYbQk?p=preview

Comment: @HarryNinh First of all thank you. Did you still changed the child.ts, right? If so I get the following error in my sublime editor: `error TS7006: Parameter 'newInterface' implicitly has an 'any' type.`

Comment: @HarryNinh I am also not able to start the server without this error is thrown.

Comment: If it is running fine on plnkr and not compiled on your editor, most likely because of tslint/tsc. Check your `tsconfig.json` file, look for the flag `"noImplicitAny"`, change it to false and try again.

Comment: @HarryNinh Finally it is working. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: No worries, I'll make this an answer for anybody to refer to if needed.

Comment: @HarryNinh Sure go ahead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error in your editor

> "Parameter 'interface' implicitly has an 'any' type."

is because you have strict TypeScript rule that prevents tsc from compiling your code. Either change the config by going to `tsconfig.json` and turn off `noImplicitAny` flag:

```
"noImplicitAny": false
```

Or add type to your interface in your `subscribe` callback:

```
globalService.interfaceChanged.subscribe((_interface: MyInterface) 
  => this.changeInterface(_interface));
```

Comment: Hey, I am now trying to handle this by using a custom pipe. Would you please take a look at it. I am stuck already. [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/SuMywz7oxsy5iM3DqOAD?p=preview)

Comment: Hey if it's not very related to this question, I think it's better for you to ask new question. It will reach more minds that way :)

Comment: Okay, I opened a new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38692577/angular2-use-global-service-through-a-custom-pipe)