# angular2 – use global service through a custom pipe

Tags: typescript, angular, pipe

I am playing around a little bit with angular 2. So far I built a global service that holds an interface. Other components are using the interface of this global service. If the interface is changed through a component the interface will also change for the child components.

Now I am trying to handle this through a pipe. But when I am changing the interface value through a child component the interface values within the other components won't change.

This is what I got so far:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

import { GlobalService } from './global-service'
import { MyInterface } from './my-interface'

@Pipe({name: 'myPipe'})
export class MyPipe implements PipeTransform {

    private value: string;

    private _interface: MyInterface;
    private interfaceChanged: EventEmitter<MyInterface>;

    constructor(private globalService: GlobalService) {

        this._interface = globalService._interface;
        this.interfaceChanged = this.globalService
                                   .interfaceChanged
                                   .subscribe((newInterface: MyInterface) => {
                                        this._interface = newInterface;
                                   });
    }

    transform(value: string, args: any[]): string {
        for (var key in this.language) {
            if (key == value) {
                this.value = this._interface[key];
                break;
            }
        }
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

Here also is a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/SuMywz7oxsy5iM3DqOAD?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pure pipes are only executed when the value or a parameter changed.

You can configure the pipe to become an impure pipe, then the pipe will be executed every time change detection runs. This can have serious performance impact though

```
@Pipe({name: 'myPipe', pure: false})
```