# Angular2 service emitter subscribe fail

Tags: angular, angular2-services

Referring to [Global Events in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34700438/global-events-in-angular-2) I am trying to implement a cart service that emits an event when a new item is added to the cart. I subscribe to this service event in another component called navbar (which is not a child of cart) where I show my number of cart items etc.

My cart service:

```
export class CartService {
    public itemAdded$: EventEmitter<any>;
    ...

    constructor(private http: Http){

        this.itemAdded$ = new EventEmitter();
        this.cart=[];
    }

    addToCart(id: any): any {

        this.itemAdded$.emit(id);

        return this.http.get(  this.myUrl + 'add' + '/' + id + '/', { withCredentials:true})
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => response.json())

    }
  ...
  ...
}
```

My navbar component:

```
@Component({
directives:[ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Cart],
providers:[CartService],

})
export class Navbar implements OnInit{

    ...
    totalCost: any;
    cartItemCount : any;
    addedItem: any;

    constructor(private cartService: CartService){

        this.cartService.itemAdded$.subscribe( (id: any) => {
            alert(id);
            this.onItemAdded(id);
            this.fetchCartElements();
        });
    }

     private onItemAdded(item: any): void {
        // do something with added item
        this.addedItem = item;
    }
...
...
}
```

However, whenever I add an item, nothing happens in the navbar i.e. `alert(id)` or `onItemAdded()` are not called automatically so that cartItemCount etc can get automatically updated.

What is going wrong?

Comment: Where did you provided this service?

Comment: I did not get your question correctly, but in my navbar component I have added it in [providers]. I updated my question with that. Cart service otherwise has nothing to do with navbar directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your error here is a conception error.

As @mxii said, your case perfectly fits `Observable` behaviour, you shouldn't use promise and an event emitter (which is called before your item is actually added on server side).

## Solution with Promise:

In case you want to fix your problem with promise, I think the solution is to trigger the event once you got your answer only:

```
    return this.http.get(  this.myUrl + 'add' + '/' + id + '/', { withCredentials:true})
    .toPromise()
    .then(response => {
                       this.cart.push(response.json());
                       this.itemAdded$.emit(id);
                       });
```

And then provide it in your top-level module (usually `AppModule`) to ensure you get only one instance accross your aplication.

## Solution with Observable:

```
addToCart(id: any): Observable<any> {//Don't you have an item interface to type the object you get?
        return this.http.get(  this.myUrl + 'add' + '/' + id + '/', { withCredentials:true})
        .map(res => res.json());
    }
```

And then on your `NavBar`:

```
@Component({
directives:[ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Cart]
//Note that I removed CartService, as I said you HAVE to provide it on the AppModule, else you'll have different instances accross your application and it seems like it's not what you want.
})
export class Navbar implements OnInit{

    ...
    totalCost: any;
    cartItemCount : any;
    addedItem: any;

    constructor(private cartService: CartService){
    }

     private onItemAdded(item: any): void {
        // do something with added item
        this.addedItem = item;
    }

    public addItemToCart(id:number):void{ 
        //I guess you're adding item from a button click, the button should call this method, passing the id of the item as parameter.
        this.cartService.addToCart(id).subscribe(this.onItemAdded);
    }
...
...
}
```

Comment: In my case I do not have addItemToCart(id:number) methos in my navbar component, I call it from another component. In navbar component, I simple fetch cart elements, and can remove them. Adding to cart happens in my different product components.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `EventEmitter` only for `@Output()`'s!

For your scenario perfectly fits an `Observable` ..

Create an `Subject` and call `next()`, it's similar to `emit()`.

```js
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

// ..

   public itemAdded$ = new Subject<any>();

// ..

   this.itemAdded$.next(id);
```

The subscribing part should be fine.

Comment: import { Subject } from 'rxjs'; gives me error saying 404 not found. However I have import { Observable  }     from 'rxjs/Observable'; which works fine..

Comment: then try this: `import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';`

Answer (score 0):

Services are singleton *per provider.* You are injecting different instances of the `CartService` to navbar and whomever is calling `addToCart` function.

I expect `Navbar` is displayed in every page of your application, so here is how to make `CartService` globally singleton.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  ],
  imports: [
  ],
  providers: [CartService], //<--- added here
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Remove any other `providers: [CartService]` from modules and components (if you are not indenting to create another instance)

Comment: And referring to above two answers, which one is more apt with your solution? event emiiter or with Subject and next()?

Comment: You need to make your service singleton as i shown in both ways.