# auth0 callback doesn't set profile date after login angular2

Tags: node.js, angular, authentication, auth0

I have an angular 2 app which uses auth0 for authentication. The issue I'm having is that when a successful login occurs, it seems like the lock callback is not being called. Only after I do a manually refresh of the page will the profile data be sent to local storage.

When a user logs in, I need to grab that profile object and use it within the component class. This code works only after I manually refresh the page following a successful login. Here is my code (only including the important parts).

auth.service

```
 lock = new Auth0Lock('.....9cNzyzJ3DZc2VpDyXSYF5', '.....12.auth0.com', {});

  user: any;

  constructor() {
    // Add callback for lock `authenticated` event
    this.user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile'));
    this.lock.on("authenticated", (authResult:any) => {
      this.lock.getProfile(authResult.idToken, function(error: any, profile: any){
        if(error){
          throw new Error(error);
        }
        localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken);
        localStorage.setItem('profile', JSON.stringify(profile));
        this.user = profile;
      });

    });
  }

  public login() {
    // Call the show method to display the widget.
    this.lock.show();
    console.log('login func');
  };
```

nav.component

```
constructor(private auth: Auth, private groupsService: GroupsService){

}

ngOnInit(){
    // need to access the profile object here. Ocject is correctly logged only after refreshing.
    console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile')));
    this.groupsService.getGroups(this.userId).subscribe(groups => {
        this.groups = groups;

        // sort the groups
        this.groups.sort((a, b) => new Date(b.date_created).getTime() - new Date(a.date_created).getTime());
    });
}
```

Comment: Hey I have the same problem. How did you solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation for `ngOnInit`](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/index/OnInit-class.html):

> `ngOnInit` is called right after the directive's data-bound properties have been checked for the first time, and before any of its children have been checked. **It is invoked only once when the directive is instantiated.**

<sub>(emphasis is mine)</sub>

Which indicates that when its run there isn't a user profile available yet because the authentication was still not processed. If you cause a page refresh after authentication, the user profile is already available in Web Storage and the manual refresh causes the `ngOnInit` to be executed leading to the behavior you described.

Comment: Ahh well I also tried putting the code from the ngOnInit into the constructor, andit had the same effect. Where should it go?

Comment: My Angular2 knowledge is limited, but you'll need to handle the authenticated event in a way that allows other components to react to the change in state (user profile availability). Check this [question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34700438/global-events-in-angular-2).