# How can create a dynamic menu in angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-services

I need to create a dynamic menu after user logged in successfully and redirected to home page using Angular 2. Exactly like in the first similar question except I cannot hardcore the menu items.

[Angular2: Using routes, how to display the navigation bar after successfully logged in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36665094/angular2-using-routes-how-to-display-the-navigation-bar-after-successfully-log)

```
#app.component.html#

<navbar>
    <!--Here I want to create menu items-->
</navbar>

<div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer" class="inner-wrap">
    <div class="row no-padding">
        <div class="col-sm-12 no-padding">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

**home.component.ts**

 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

 import { User } from '../_models/index';
 import { UserService } from '../_services/index';

@Component({
//moduleId: module.id,
templateUrl: 'home.component.html'
 })

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
users: User[] = [];

constructor(private userService: UserService) { }

 ngOnInit() {
  <!-- how we can create it here or any better place -->
    // get users from secure api end point
    this.userService.getUsers()
        .subscribe(users => {
            this.users = users;
        });
   }

}
```

Clearly I am new to this technology. Please anybody pick this up?

Blockquote

Comment: @Downvoter, care to explain the downvote?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I managed to Create dynamic menu based on user access right after the user logs in. I think I was not able to articulate the requirement properly in my original question. Yesterday, while searching "how to make 2 components communicate with each other" I found this on the angular website (see link below):

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/EventEmitter-class.html

We can achieve this by using a Global EventEmitter. Here is how I implemented it in my code:

GlobalEventManager:

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export class GlobalEventsManager {
    public showNavBar: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
    public hideNavBar: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
}
```

The below link will help you to understand how to implement auth guard (restricting a user to enter without login).

http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/08/16/angular-2-jwt-authentication-example-tutorial

Auth.Guard.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { GlobalEventsManager } from "../_common/gobal-events-manager";

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private router: Router, private globalEventsManager: GlobalEventsManager) { }

    canActivate() {

        if (localStorage.getItem('currentUser')) {

            this.globalEventsManager.showNavBar.emit(true);
            return true;
        }
        else {
            // not logged in so redirect to login page
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
            this.globalEventsManager.hideNavBar.emit(true);
            return;
        }


    }
}
```

Model used in menu.component.ts

Features:

```
export class Features {
    Description: string;
    RoutePath: string;
}
```

menu.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Features } from '../_models/features';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { GlobalEventsManager } from "../_common/gobal-events-manager";

@Component({
    selector: 'nav',
    templateUrl: './menu.component.html'
})

export class MenuComponent {

    showNavBar: boolean = false;
    featureList: Features[] = [];
    private headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });

    constructor(private http: Http, private router: Router, private globalEventsManager: GlobalEventsManager) {

        this.globalEventsManager.showNavBar.subscribe((mode: any) => {
            this.showNavBar = mode;

            if (this.showNavBar = true) {
    <!-- the below function expects user id, here I have given as 1 -->
                this.getFeatureListByLoggedInUser(1)
                    .then(list => { this.featureList = list; });
            }
        });

        this.globalEventsManager.hideNavBar.subscribe((mode: any) => {
            this.showNavBar = false;
            this.featureList = [];
        });
    }

    private getFeatureListByLoggedInUser(userID: number): Promise<Features[]> {
        return this.http.get(your api url + '/Feature/GetFeatureListByUserID?userID=' + userID)
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => response.json() as Features[])
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
        console.error('An error occurred', error); // for demo purposes only
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }
}
```

Menu.Component.html:

```
<div id="navbar" *ngIf="showNavBar" class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-collapse-custom">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav_menu full-width">
        <li *ngFor="let feature of featureList" class="nav_menu" routerLinkActive="active"><a class="nav-item nav-link" [routerLink]="[feature.routepath]" routerLinkActive="active">{{feature.description}}</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

App.Component.ts:

```
    <!-- menu container -->
    <nav>
    </nav>
    <!-- main app container -->
    <div class="container-fluid body-content-custom">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 no-padding">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer class="footer">
        &nbsp;
    </footer>


In the last, we need to register the providers of menu and global event manager in app.module.ts

app.module.ts

/// <reference path="reset-password/reset-password.component.ts" />
/// <reference path="reset-password/reset-password.component.ts" />
import './rxjs-extensions';
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule, XHRBackend } from '@angular/http';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { AuthGuard } from './_guards/auth.guard';

import { ContentHeaders } from './_common/headers';
import { GlobalEventsManager } from "./_common/gobal-events-manager";
import { MenuComponent } from "./menu/menu.component";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        MenuComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        AuthGuard,
        ContentHeaders,
        GlobalEventsManager
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I hope this will help!

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I do.  Basically, the flow is set up a listener in app component that subscribes to an observable of getLoggedIn.  When that observable emits (user logs in), I call the app.menu.service get logged in menu.  On logout, the reverse is true and I get noLoginMenu.

app.menu.service:

```
import {RouterModule, RouterLinkActive, RouterLink} from '@angular/router';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { Observable  } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable()
export class AppMenuService {

  constructor() {

  }

  getNoLoginMenu() {
    return [
      {
        label: 'Home',
        routerLink: ['']
      },  {
        label: 'Documents',
        routerLink: ['/document']
      }, {
        label: 'Calculator',
        routerLink: ['/calculator']
      }, {
        label: 'Verify',
        routerLink: ['/verify']
      }, {
        label: 'About',
        routerLink: ['/about']
      }];
  }

  getLoggedInMenu() {
    return [
      {
        label: 'Home',
        routerLink: ['']
      }, {
        label: 'Documents',
        routerLink: ['/document']
      }, {
        label: 'Food',
        routerLink: ['/food']
      }, {
        label: 'Calculator',
        routerLink: ['/calculator']
      }, {
        label: 'Settings',
        routerLink: ['/settings']
      }, {
        label: 'Themes',
        routerLink: ['/themes']
      }, {
        label: 'About',
        routerLink: ['/about']
      }, {
        label: 'Logout',
        routerLink: ['/logout']
        //command: (event: Event) => { this.onLogout() }
      }];
  }
}
```

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    private items: MenuItem[];
    appPageHeaderDivStyle: {};
    selectedTheme: Theme;
    errorMessage: string;
    loggedIn: LoggedIn;
    loggedInEmail: string = "";
    isLoggedIn: boolean;
    themeSub: Subscription;
    loggedInSub: Subscription;
    profileSub: Subscription;

    constructor(
        private as: AppMenuService,
        private ts: ThemeService,
        private ss: SettingsService,
        private fs: FoodService,
        private ls: LoginService) {
    }

    @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
    beforeUnloadHander(event) {
        var shutdown = this.onShutdown();
        //event.preventDefault();

    }

    ngOnInit() {

        this.themeSub = this.ts.getNewTheme()
            .subscribe(
            theme => this.selectedTheme = theme,
            error => {
                this.errorMessage = error
            },
            () => this.completeGetNewTheme()
            );

        this.ts.setTheme("Pepper-Grinder");
        this.items = this.as.getNoLoginMenu();

        this.ls.getLoggedIn()
            .subscribe(
            loggedIn => {
                if (loggedIn.error != undefined && loggedIn.error === "" && loggedIn.email != "") {
                    this.items = this.as.getLoggedInMenu();

                    var us = this.ss.getUserSettings();
                    if (us != undefined && us.theme != null && us.theme != "") {
                        this.ts.setTheme(us.theme);
                    }


                }
                else {
                    this.items = this.as.getNoLoginMenu();
                    this.ts.setTheme("Pepper-Grinder");
                }

                this.completeLoggedIn(loggedIn.email);
            });
    }


    ngOnDestroy() {
        if (this.themeSub) {
            this.themeSub.unsubscribe();
        }

        if(this.loggedInSub) {
            this.loggedInSub.unsubscribe();
        }

        if(this.profileSub) {
            this.profileSub.unsubscribe();
        }
    }


    completeLoggedIn(email: string) {
        this.loggedInEmail = email;
        this.isLoggedIn = (this.loggedInEmail.length > 0);
    }

    completeGetNewTheme() {
        this.appPageHeaderDivStyle = this.ts.getAppPageHeaderDivStyle();
    }

    onShutdown(): boolean {
        var ok = true;
        this.fs.completeUpdateDailyFood();
        this.profileSub = this.ss.updateProfileInformation(this.ss.getUserSettings())
            .subscribe(
            status => {
                console.log("logout - updated user");
            },
            error => {
                ok = false;
            },
        );
        return ok;
    }

    onLogout() {
    }
}
```

LoginService:

```
 loginUser(localUser: LocalUser) {
        this.authSub = this.auth.loginUser(localUser)
            .subscribe(
            token => {
                this.token = token
            },
            error => {
                this.isLoggingIn = false;
                var errorObject = JSON.parse(error._body);
                this.errorMessage = errorObject.error_description;
                console.log(this.errorMessage);
                this.setLoggedIn({ email: "", password: "", error: this.errorMessage });

            },
            () => this.completeLogin(localUser));
    }
```

Comment: HI John, thanks for your early response. But this doesn't solve my problem. Actually I want to create a dynamic menu depending on the user's rights, in angular 2? The navigation bar is in app.component.html but I need to create through home.component.ts file. I hope it make sense to you now.

Answer (score -1):

I did this by running the menu items array through a filter based on the user's rights.
[Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)