# unable to hide header and footer from login page using angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

here my issue i unable to hide the header and footer from the login page . here i am having a common header and footer in app.html and login page & home page. With out login it does not have to show the nav but still i am getting the nav before authentication

below is my code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar fixed-top" style="background-color:grey">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right landing-nav-text ul-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="#about">About <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#features">Features</a></li>
                <li><a href="#info">info</a></li>
                <li><a href="#demo">Demo</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#demo1">Demo1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#demo2">Demo2</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#demo3">Demo3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
     <a (click)="Logout()" class="logout">
        Logout
    </a>
</nav>
<router-outlet><router-outlet>


<div class="footer">
    <div class="main_content">

        <div class="footer_links_end">
          <p>This is footer</p>

            <p>
                <a href="https://twitter.com">Twitter</a>
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com">Linkedin</a>

            </p>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

please check this stack for issue

Comment: you  need hide logout button from the nav bar or complete navbar?

Comment: complete nav bar & footer from login page

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36665094/angular2-using-routes-how-to-display-the-navigation-bar-after-successfully-log this can be helpful

Comment: Best way of doing this is making a layout component and using child routing

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [*`ngIf`*](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf):

for, that you have to use Router from ***@angular/router***.

Component.ts:

```
import { Router }  from "@angular/router";
...

constructor(public router: Router){} // note you have to use Public because you are using it in html file too.
```

Component.html:

```
<nav *ngIf="router.url !== '/login' && router.url !== '/signup'"> // or maybe only 'login'
</nav>
```

Note: If you are using different components for the header (`<app-header>`) and footer(`<app-footer>`) you can use *ngIf with them too..

Answer (score 1):

2 changes can help you achieve this...

- a boolean flag which is set after calling the getUser from your service... in case of a valid user, we set boolean to true and navigation gets displayed
- in the HTML, we just set the ngIf against this boolean variable

```js
/* APP.COMPONENT.TS */
  hideName:boolean =true;
  
  constructor(public _authService:AuthService,public router:Router){
    if(this._authService.getUser() == ''){
      this.hideName = false;
    }
    else {
      this.hideName =true;
    }
  }
```

```html
  <!-- Added *ngIf="hideName" to app.component.html -->
  
  <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar fixed-top" style="background-color:grey"  *ngIf="hideName">
```

Answer (score 1):

Because in your app.component.html (the page you use to display your outlet), you are inserting the code directly:

```
< Your header code >

....

<router-outlet></router-outlet>

....

< Your footer code >
```

The solution, is to:

- Remove the header and footer code to a separate component, such as HeaderComponent, and FooterComponent, and then,
- Call the outlet only on pages that you want them to show, by using proper selector.

For example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uhvgjm (I have done some part, you need to continue yourself when you want to show the header and footer)

Answer (score 0):

you can use an injectable class with Subject inside and push anything you need to the header from any event you want

```
import {EventEmitter, Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Subject, Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HeaderManagerService {
  private headerStatus = new Subject<any>();

  constructor() {
  }

  changeHeader(showHeader: boolean, rightBtn: string | undefined, onRightBtn: EventEmitter<boolean> | undefined, onLeftBtn: EventEmitter<boolean> | undefined) {
    this.headerStatus.next({showHeader, rightBtn, onRightBtn, onLeftBtn});
  }

  getHeaderStatus(): Observable<any> {
    return this.headerStatus.asObservable();
  }
}
```

and in your NavComponent

```
  protected onDestroy = new Subject<void>();
  showHeader = true;
  rightBtn: string | undefined;
  onRightBtn: EventEmitter<boolean> | undefined;
  onLeftBtn: EventEmitter<boolean> | undefined;

  constructor(private headerManager: HeaderManagerService,
              private router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.onDestroy.next();
    this.onDestroy.complete();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.router.events
      .pipe(filter(navigation => navigation instanceof NavigationEnd))
      .subscribe((s: any) => {
        this.showHeader = true;
        this.rightBtn = undefined;
        this.onRightBtn = undefined;
        this.onLeftBtn = undefined;
      });
    this.headerManager.getHeaderStatus()
      .pipe(
        skipWhile(val => !val),
        takeUntil(this.onDestroy)
      )
      .subscribe(({showHeader, rightBtn, onRightBtn, onLeftBtn}) => {
        this.showHeader = showHeader;
        this.rightBtn = rightBtn;
        this.onRightBtn = onRightBtn;
        this.onLeftBtn = onLeftBtn;
      });
  }
```

in nav.component.html

```
<nav *ngIf="showHeader">
  some header
</nav>
<nav *ngIf="!showHeader">  <!--or ignore this element-->
  <div class="d-flex">
    <button (click)="onLeftBtn?.emit(true)">back</button>
    <div class="flex-grow-1"></div>
    <div (click)="onRightBtn?.emit(true)" [innerHTML]="rightBtn ?? ''"></div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

and push some change to header from your page

```
  constructor(private headerManager: HeaderManagerService) {
  }
  onLeftBtn = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  onRightBtn = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.headerManager.changeHeader(false,
      '<img class="word-arrow mb-4" src="assets/img/myimage.jpg">',
      this.onRightBtn,
      this.onLeftBtn);
    this.onLeftBtn.subscribe((value) => {
      console.log('onLeftBtn');
    });
    this.onRightBtn.subscribe((value) => {
      console.log('onRightBtn');
    });
  }
```